# Monitoring Broker Redelivery with ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, monitoring, jmx

We have configured our ActiveMQ Broker with the Broker redelivery Plugin using this configuration.

```
<redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true"
                sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
    <redeliveryPolicyMap>
        <redeliveryPolicyMap>
            <redeliveryPolicyEntries>
            </redeliveryPolicyEntries>
            <!-- the fallback policy for all other destinations -->
            <defaultEntry>
                <redeliveryPolicy
                    maximumRedeliveries="15"
                    useExponentialBackOff="true"
                    initialRedeliveryDelay="5000"
                    useCollisionAvoidance="true"
                    backOffMultiplier="5"
                    maximumRedeliveryDelay="93600000" />
            </defaultEntry>
        </redeliveryPolicyMap>
    </redeliveryPolicyMap>
</redeliveryPlugin>
```

The plugin performs as expected removing the failed message from the queue and retrying it at the specified intervals.

The problem we now face is that we need to monitor how many message are currently waiting to be retried for each queue, since they will not show up as waiting in the normal queue monitoring. I could not find anything in the JMX tree for ActiveMQ related to the redeliveryPlugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages are stored in the JobSchedulerStore which is a separate store from the normal AMQ KahaDB or JDBC stores.  There's less visibility into this store however there should be an MBean for it.  You can get some information via JMX or you can get information by sending JMS Messages with special headers set.  There is an article on the JMS style administration [here](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/10/enhanced-jms-scheduler-in-activemq.html).

Comment: From what I can see, is that you can only query for the messages that are scheduled in a certain time interval, but this will give you the whole message instead of just meta information, which makes it impractical if you want to monitor (e.g. every X Seconds) how many message are currently scheduled. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, the monitoring capabilities are limited.  On trunk there are some additional methods in the MBean to aid in monitoring.  The project is open source, so you can contribute the functionality you need.